# Not able to read the child list from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to display the list of items inside a collection in my flutter app.. But not able to get it done.

This is my code. Not sure where I am doing wrong.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: dbRef.once(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      lists.clear();
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
      if (values != null) {
        print(values);
        values.forEach((key, values) {                   
          lists.add(values);
        });
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: lists.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.book_online),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                title: Text(
                  lists[index]["Name"],
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                dense: true,
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Book',
                      arguments: {"id": lists[index]["ID"]});
                },
              );
            });
      } else {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'No books found in your Library',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }),
```

The Console Output I am getting is as follows

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: How is your `dbRef` initialized?

Comment: Those are the screen shots of the database and the console output

Comment: final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
  
    final ref = fb.reference();
 final dbRef = ref.child("MyLibrary").orderByKey().equalTo(uid);

Comment: You might also want to `print(lists)` after you populate it.

Comment: @iShah Please don't provide code in the comments, but edit your question by clicking the link right under it.

Answer (score 1):

You are querying `MyLibrary`, which means the nodes in the result are direct child nodes of `MyLibrary`. What you want instead is to get the book nodes for a psecific user. In that case, don't use a query, but directly look up the books for that user with:

```
final dbRef = ref.child("MyLibrary").child(uid);
```

Comment: Wow.. It worked like a charm.. thanks a million